# How can I remove blank cells from a column having images?

Tags: excel, image

I have an excel sheet with one column having images. I need to delete every row which do not contain an image. So, I need to get hold of all the cells from the images containing column. Please help

Comment: Are the images completely enclosed within single cells or do they overlap several cells ?

Comment: I have made sure that each image is enclosed within separate cell and the images don't overlap or interfere with other images

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for images in column **A**

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim s As Shape, rPic As Range, r As Range
    Dim wMAX As Long, i As Long
    Set rPic = Nothing

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Set r = s.TopLeftCell
        If wMAX < r.Row Then
            wMAX = r.Row
        End If
        If rPic Is Nothing Then
            Set rPic = r
        Else
            Set rPic = Union(rPic, r)
        End If
    Next s

    For i = wMAX To 1 Step -1
        If Intersect(rPic, Cells(i, 1)) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]